# How do I reset the GUI and the Game?

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, jbutton

I am making a game and would like to reset the board once the game is over and the rest button is clicked. Currently the game plays well the first run.

I think the problem is in the reset method "this.play()". Can someone please explain what is going on when I call it.

With the "this.play()" the GUI doesn't reset and the game doesn't play. Without the "this.play()" the GUI resets but the game doesn't work.

Also I would like to run the check method after each button click instead of a loop. I keep getting errors that non-static method can not be refered from a static context. I have been putting the check method in the actionPerformed method of the buttons class

Here is my code...

Board class ...

```
public class ticTacBoard extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
Toebuttons toe[] = new Toebuttons[9];
JFrame over = new JFrame("Game Over");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel winner = new JLabel("");
static boolean win = false;
public static void start()
{ 
    ticTacBoard b = new ticTacBoard();
    b.play();
}
public void play()
{
    //ticTacBoard one = new ticTacBoard();
    while(!win && Toebuttons.count < 9)
    {
        this.check();
    }
    endFrame();
}

public ticTacBoard()
{
    super("Tic tac board");
    toFront();
    setSize(500,500);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    for(int i = 0; i<toe.length; i++)
    {
        toe[i] = new Toebuttons();
        add(toe[i]);
    }
    setVisible(true);
}

public void check()
{
    checkRow();
    checkDiagonal();
    checkColumn();
}

public void checkRow()
{

    if((toe[0].getText().equals("X")||toe[0].getText().equals("O"))&&(toe[0].getText().equals(toe[1].getText()) && toe[1].getText().equals(toe[2].getText())))
    {
        winner.setText(toe[2].getText()+" WINS!!!\nROW");
        win = true;
    }
    if((toe[3].getText().equals("X")||toe[3].getText().equals("O"))&&(toe[3].getText().equals(toe[4].getText()) && toe[4].getText().equals(toe[5].getText())))
    {
        winner.setText(toe[3].getText()+" WINS!!!\nROW");
        win = true;
    }
    if((toe[6].getText().equals("X")||toe[6].getText().equals("O"))&&(toe[6].getText().equals(toe[7].getText()) && toe[7].getText().equals(toe[8].getText())))
    {
        winner.setText(toe[6].getText()+" WINS!!!\nROW");
        win = true;
    }
}

public void checkDiagonal()
{
    if((toe[0].getText().equals("X")||toe[0].getText().equals("O"))&&(toe[0].getText().equals(toe[4].getText()) && toe[4].getText().equals(toe[8].getText())))
    {
        winner.setText(toe[0].getText()+" WINS!!!\nDIAGONAL");
        win = true;
    }
    if((toe[2].getText().equals("X")||toe[2].getText().equals("O"))&&(toe[2].getText().equals(toe[4].getText()) && toe[4].getText().equals(toe[6].getText())))
    {
        winner.setText(toe[0].getText()+" WINS!!!\nDIAGONAL");
        win = true;
    }
}

public void checkColumn()
{
    if((toe[0].getText().equals("X")||toe[0].getText().equals("O"))&&(toe[0].getText().equals(toe[3].getText()) && toe[3].getText().equals(toe[6].getText())))
    {
        winner.setText(toe[0].getText()+" WINS!!!\nCOLUMN");
        win = true;
    }
    if((toe[1].getText().equals("X")||toe[1].getText().equals("O"))&&(toe[1].getText().equals(toe[4].getText()) && toe[4].getText().equals(toe[7].getText())))
    {
        winner.setText(toe[1].getText()+" WINS!!!\nCOLUMN");
        win = true;
    }
    if((toe[2].getText().equals("X")||toe[2].getText().equals("O"))&&(toe[2].getText().equals(toe[5].getText()) && toe[5].getText().equals(toe[8].getText())))
    {
        winner.setText(toe[2].getText()+" WINS!!!\nCOLUMN");
        win = true;
    }
}
public void endFrame()
{
    System.out.println("2222");
    over.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    over.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(winner);
    panel.repaint();
    over.add(panel);
    over.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    over.setSize(500,100);
    JButton r = new JButton("Reset");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(r);
    over.add(p);
    r.addActionListener(this);
    over.repaint();
    over.setVisible(true);
}
public void reset()
{
    Toebuttons.x = true;
    for(int i = 0; i<toe.length;i++)
    { 
        toe[i].setText("blank");
    }
    win = false;
    Toebuttons.count = 0;
    this.play();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    over.hide();
    reset();
}
}
```

Button Class ...

```
 public class Toebuttons extends JButton implements ActionListener
 {
 static boolean x = true;// if true x's turn if false o's turn
 public static int count = 0; 
 public Toebuttons()
 {
   super("blank");
   this.addActionListener(this);
 }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
   if(this.x == true && getText().equals("blank") && !ticTacBoard.win)
   {
       count++;
       System.out.println(count);
       setText("X");
       this.x = false;
   }
   else if(this.x == false && getText().equals("blank")&& !ticTacBoard.win)
   {
       count++;
       System.out.println(count);
       setText("O");
       this.x = true;
   }

   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> With the "this.play()" the GUI doesn't reset and the game doesn't play. Without the "this.play()" the GUI resets but the game doesn't work.

The problem is, you're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread...

```
public void play()
{
    //ticTacBoard one = new ticTacBoard();
    while(!win && Toebuttons.count < 9)
    {
        this.check();
    }
    endFrame();
}
```

This is creating an infinite loop which is preventing the Event Queue from been processed by the Event Dispatching Thread.

> But why does it work the first time?

Because you've actually violated one of the basic rules of GUI development.  `main` is called in, what is typically known as, the "main thread".  This means that the first time you call `play`, you are running on a different thread from the Event Dispatching Thread.  However, the second time you call it, `reset` is been called from within the context of the EDT, which is then causing `play` to block it.

Some basic rules of GUI development:

- Don't perform long running or blocking operations within the UI thread
- Don't update the UI or a state the UI depends on, from outside the context of the UI thread.  Most UI APIs are not thread safe.

This is large and some what complex subject, but, you can start by having a read through [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

> So, what's the solution?

UI's are event driven, you should use this mechanism to monitor when the button states are changed and perform your update checks then.

First, get rid of `play`

Second, attach a `ActionListener` to all your buttons on the board.  As part of there "operation", you should check the state of the play and make decisions about what should be done.

And, no, I don't mean adding the checks into `Toebuttons#actionPerformed`, I mean `ticTacBoard` should register it's own `ActionListener` on the `Toebuttons` and when triggered, check the state of play - just beware, the order the `ActionListener`s are called my effect your decision making process, this is why it would be better to separate the state of the UI from the state of the game play - but that's another subject

## Conceptual Runnable Example...

This is a conceptual example, it introduces the concept of decoupling the UI from the game state and makes the UI responsible for only displaying the game state.

See:

- [Understanding Model-View-Controller](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) and [Design Patterns - MVC Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm)
- [Design Patterns - Observer Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) - this is basically what "listeners" are in Swing. [Introduction to Event Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html).  Most GUIs are a event driven environment, meaning that something happens and then you respond to it, they occur in a non-linear fashion.
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)
- [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Dig through it, put in some `System.out.println` statements, run a debugger over the code.  Go back to the linked tutorials and expand your understanding of the concepts presented

While some might consider it "advanced", conceptually, this introduces the core concepts you will need to understand in order to work with Swing and GUIs in general

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TicTac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTac();
    }

    public TicTac() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TicTacToePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum Player {
        X, O, NONE;
    }

    public interface TicTacToeModelListener {

        public void ticTacToeGameWon(TicTacToeModel model);
    }

    public class TicTacToeModel {

        private Player[] board;
        private Player turn;
        private Player winner;

        private List<TicTacToeModelListener> listeners;

        public TicTacToeModel() {
            board = new Player[3 * 3];
            listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
            reset();
        }

        public boolean isX() {
            return turn == Player.X;
        }

        public void nextTurn() {
            if (isX()) {
                turn = Player.O;
            } else {
                turn = Player.X;
            }
        }

        public Player getTurn() {
            return turn;
        }

        public Player getWinner() {
            return winner;
        }

        public void reset() {
            for (int index = 0; index < board.length; index++) {
                board[index] = Player.NONE;
            }
            turn = Player.X;
            winner = Player.NONE;
        }

        public void set(int col, int row) {
            int index = (row * 3) + col;
            if (board[index] == Player.NONE) {
                board[index] = turn;
            } else {
                System.out.println("!! Spot already occupied");
            }

            check();
        }

        public void check() {
            checkRow();
            checkDiagonal();
            checkColumn();

            if (winner != Player.NONE) {
                fireGameWon();
            }
        }

        public void addModelListener(TicTacToeModelListener listener) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }

        public void removeModelListener(TicTacToeModelListener listener) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }

        protected void fireGameWon() {
            for (TicTacToeModelListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.ticTacToeGameWon(this);
            }
        }

        public void checkRow() {

            if ((board[0] == Player.X || board[0] == Player.O) && (board[0] == board[1] && board[1] == board[2])) {
                winner = turn;
            }
            if ((board[3] == Player.X || board[3] == Player.O) && (board[3] == board[4] && board[4] == board[5])) {
                winner = turn;
            }
            if ((board[6] == Player.X || board[6] == Player.O) && (board[6] == board[7] && board[7] == board[8])) {
                winner = turn;
            }
        }

        public void checkDiagonal() {
            if ((board[0] == Player.X || board[0] == Player.O) && (board[0] == (board[4]) && board[4] == (board[8]))) {
                winner = turn;
            }
            if ((board[2] == Player.X || board[2] == Player.O) && (board[2] == (board[4]) && board[4] == (board[6]))) {
                winner = turn;
            }
        }

        public void checkColumn() {
            if ((board[0] == Player.X || board[0] == Player.O) && (board[0] == (board[3]) && board[3] == (board[6]))) {
                winner = turn;
            }
            if ((board[1] == Player.X || board[1] == Player.O) && (board[1] == (board[4]) && board[4] == (board[7]))) {
                winner = turn;
            }
            if ((board[2] == Player.X || board[2] == Player.O) && (board[2] == (board[5]) && board[5] == (board[8]))) {
                winner = turn;
            }
        }
    }

    public class TicTacToePane extends JPanel {

        private TicTacToeModel model;
        private GamePane gamePane;
        private WinPane winPane;

        public TicTacToePane() {
            CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

            model = new TicTacToeModel();
            model.addModelListener(new TicTacToeModelListener() {
                @Override
                public void ticTacToeGameWon(TicTacToeModel model) {
                    winPane.setWinner(model.getWinner());
                    cardLayout.show(TicTacToePane.this, "GameOverMan");
                }
            });

            winPane = new WinPane();
            gamePane = new GamePane(model);

            winPane.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getActionCommand().equals(GameActions.PLAY_AGAIN.getCommand())) {
                        gamePane.reset();
                        cardLayout.show(TicTacToePane.this, "ReadyPlayer");
                    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(GameActions.STOP_PLAYING.getCommand())) {
                        SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TicTacToePane.this).dispose();
                    }
                }
            });

            setLayout(cardLayout);
            add(winPane, "GameOverMan");
            add(gamePane, "ReadyPlayer");

            cardLayout.show(this, "ReadyPlayer");
            System.out.println("...");
        }

    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        private JButton board[];
        private TicTacToeModel model;

        public GamePane(TicTacToeModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            board = new JButton[9];
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    int index = (row * 3) + col;
                    System.out.println(index);
                    board[index] = new JButton("-"); // Icon might be better
                    board[index].addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener(col, row));
                    add(board[index]);
                }
            }
            reset();
        }

        public void reset() {
            model.reset();
            for (int index = 0; index < board.length; index++) {
                board[index].setText("-");
            }
        }

        protected class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

            private int col;
            private int row;

            public ButtonActionListener(int col, int row) {
                this.col = col;
                this.row = row;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Normally I'd use instanceof to check the source, but
                // I've deliberly limited the possible scope.
                JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
                btn.setText(model.isX() ? "X" : "0");
                model.set(col, row);
                model.nextTurn();
            }

        }
    }

    public enum GameActions {
        PLAY_AGAIN("playAgain"), STOP_PLAYING("stopPlaying");

        private String command;

        private GameActions(String command) {
            this.command = command;
        }

        public String getCommand() {
            return command;
        }
    }

    public class WinPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel winner;
        private JButton playAgain;
        private JButton end;

        public WinPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

            winner = new JLabel("");
            playAgain = new JButton("Play Again");
            playAgain.setActionCommand(GameActions.PLAY_AGAIN.getCommand());

            end = new JButton("Stop Playing");
            end.setActionCommand(GameActions.STOP_PLAYING.getCommand());

            add(new JLabel("Game Over!"), gbc);
            add(new JLabel("Player"), gbc);
            add(winner, gbc);
            add(new JLabel("Wins!"), gbc);

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
            buttons.add(playAgain);
            buttons.add(end);

            add(buttons, gbc);
        }

        public void setWinner(Player player) {
            if (player == Player.X) {
                winner.setText("X");
            } else if (player == Player.O) {
                winner.setText("0");
            } else {
                winner.setText("No boby knows");
            }
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            playAgain.addActionListener(listener);
            end.addActionListener(listener);
        }

        public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            playAgain.removeActionListener(listener);
            end.removeActionListener(listener);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I would want to start the whole program by calling a static method though. Is that possible?

Comment: Why? What benefit would you gain? Besides, once you get rid of `play`, you can just keep on calling the `static` method till the cows come home

Comment: `play`'s not static, `start` is.  But since you've already reset the state of the current board, I don't see the point in calling it again, you've already reset the state of the UI/game, just keep using the current instance you've got - otherwise the whole concept of the `reset` method makes no sense, just create a new instance of the board and dispose of the current one :/

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from the play method into the static method start() and called start instead, but it's the same error. How would I dispose one instance of board and create another? I like that idea

Comment: Yes, because, you've just done the same thing - did you not read the answer? Did you not read the tutorials?

Comment: @MadProgrammer What tutorials do you reccomend I read? How would I dispose the current instance of board and create a new one? I am trying to get better at GUI and event handling. I wanted to do this project as a why to improve. Do you recommend anything else to get better at GUI and event handling?

Comment: @Ben [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) would be the first.  You already seem to understand how to use buttons and `ActionListener`, just don't know why you're not using them on the board

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know how to write them. I don't fully understand how to use them.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So how would I disspose and create a new instance of the board? Would it work with the way the buttons are created?

Comment: @Ben You already are - the problem is, as I've stated, you're violating the single threaded nature of the API - GET RID OF THE PLAY METHOD - do not "loop" within the Event Dispatching Thread - use the event driven nature of the API to check the state of the game each time another button is clicked

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Would appear the OP doesn't like hearing "don't do it the way you are, you need to change" :/ - Have water, can't force 'em to drink ... tempted to drown them though